# Microsoft J Script runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object - what does this mean

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

When running a report, the runtime error displays when a openNewWinNoTB is called.  I've included the code block below.

```
  function openNewWin(url) {
        var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'width=1100,height=800,left=200,top=50,toolbar=1,resizable=1,status=1,scrollbars=1');
        x.focus();
    }
```

Comment: you call openNewWinNoTB ? here you have a function called openNewWin - can you at least not have bugs on the question ? :)

Comment: Aristos, my apologies.  I runtime error occurs when openNewWin (url) is called.  The x.focus is highlighted when the error msg displays.  Thank you for catching that for me.